# iOS non returnable navigation

Tags: ios, navigation

My iOS app is full screen. Its first page presents the user with some statements and a button to proceed to a screen which will serve as a main screen. Users are to be prevented from navigating back to the first screen once they have entered the main screen. Do I need a `UINavigationController` to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways you can do this. Consider the following:

1. Have your main screen be the "root" viewcontroller and modally show
   the first screen. Once the user enters the information required for the first screen, dismiss the view and there's no way the user can navigate back to the first view.
2. Opposite of the first idea, have your first screen as the root view controller and modally show the main screen. The user would not be able to navigate back to the first screen without dismissing the modal view, which you simply do not provide a way for.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your mainScreen ViewController. This will disable pan gesture recognition responsible for poping the view controller:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)])
       self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```